# How to track a remote git branch?

Tags: git, branch, fetch

I have two branches, `master` and `mybranch` in a git repository.
In a local folder cloned from the git repository before adding the second branch, I can only see the first branch, as expected:

```
xxx$ git branch
* master
```

In an attempt to fetch the other branch I tried

```
xxx$git branch --track mybranch
```

which returns

```
Branch origin/mybranch set up to track local branch master
```

which is not what I want, because from what I understand now my local branch `mybranch` is the same as `master` (right?).

So I have 2 questions:

- how do I remove this local branch?
- how can I really fetch the remote branch `mybranch`?

**EDIT** I don't want to checkout `mybranch`, I just want to fetch.

**EDIT 2**

In the workspace w2 in which I created the branch (I cloned the repos, created `mybranch` and pushed it:

```
$ git branch -vv
  master    c417738 [origin/master] <latest commit msg>
* mybranch 0c7dbac <latest commit msg>
```

In the initial workspace w1 (where I first pushed `master`)

```
$ git branch -vv
* master 66bb412 <latest commit msg>
```

Now if I do a fetch in w1:

```
$ git fetch
```

I still have only `master`:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master 66bb412 <latest commit msg>
```

But if I check my remote branches, both `master` and `mybranch` exist:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/master
  origin/mybranch
```

So `fetch` did not get the data from all branches, as I expected...

**EDIT 3**

Now, following Klas Mellbourn's instructions, I did:

```
git branch mybranch
```

And added these lines to my conf file:

```
[branch "mybranch"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

And now checking my branches I get:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master    66bb412 <latest commit msg>
  mybranch 66bb412 [origin/mybranch: ahead 3, behind 8] <latest commit msg from master (?)>
```

Why is the commit specified for `mybranch` the same as the one specified for `master`? And why does it specify the same commit number as the `master`'s one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you actually probably did

```
git branch --track origin/mybranch
```

Which created a local branch confusingly named `origin/mybranch` that tracks the local branch you were currently on

Delete that branch

```
git branch -d origin/mybranch
```

To get the remote branch simply do

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Which should return

```
Branch mybranch set up to track remote branch mybranch from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'
```

If it does not, you can do

```
git checkout -b mybranch
git branch -u origin/mybranch
```

(Or the more succinct `git checkout -t origin/mybranch` that VonC suggests in his answer)

If it is important to you not to check out the new branch, you can do

```
git branch mybranch
git branch -u origin/mybranch mybranch
```

If you are using git 1.7 (which does not have the `-u` switch) and you absolutely do not 
want to checkout the tracking branch, I don't think you can create it using the command line, but you can edit the config file directly

```
git branch mybranch
git config --local --edit
```

Then add these lines

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

Tip: you can study the output of `git branch -vva` to get an understanding of your branches:

Comment: You're right for the actual branch name. I tried `git checkout mybranch` and got: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: <list of files>`. I just want to fetch the branch, I don't want to change my current branch (master). Is that possible?

Comment: @jul If you *just* want to fetch the remote branch, an ordinary `git fetch` is enough. If you want to create a local tracking branch without checking it out, you can do `git branch mybranch` to create it, and then `git branch -u origin/mybranch mybranch` to make it track `origin/mybranch`

Comment: I tried `git fetch`, but afterwards `git branch` still returns only `*master` (`git branch -r` does show both branches `master` and `mybranch`).

Comment: Ok, so as described in your comment, it seems I must first create `mybranch` locally, and then make it track the remote `mybranch`, right? There is no way to just make git get all the data from all the remote branches? Anyway, I tried `git branch --set-upstream mybranch origin/mybranch` (I'm using git 1.7, so the -u option does not exist), then `git fetch`, but the local `mybranch` still does not seem to be the same as the remote branch: I tried `git diff master..mybranch` and it shows no difference.

Comment: @jul `git fetch` does "get all the data from all the remote branches", it will automatically populate the remote branch `origin/mybranch` which after that can be found in your local repository.

Comment: @jul About your problems with `mybranch`: what does `git branch -vv` say? What does it indicate that `mybranch` is tracking?

Comment: @jul `git fetch` did get the data, it got it into the remote branch `origin/mybranch` that *actually exists* in your local repository (with it's commits). I have updated my answer with more instructions.

Comment: So if `mybranch` exists locally, why is it not visible with `git branch`, and why do I have to create it with `git branch mybranch`?

Comment: @jul `origin/mybranch` is visible with `git branch -r`. You are not allowed to make direct modifications to remote branches. Remote branches are supposed to contain copies of the content of remote repositories. You create local branches to make your local changes on. Then you push those changes to the remote repositories, and the same changes are copied to your own remote branches. This is a good explanation of the situation http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/

Comment: I tried you command, i.e. creating the branch and adding its data to the git conf file, and when checking the branches with `git branch -vv` it returns for `mybranch` that I'm `ahead 3, behind 8`. Why if I haven't done any changes? I updated my question.

Comment: It says `ahead 3, behind 8` because your local mybranch has diverged from the remote. You have made three commits locally that are not in the remote and someone else has made 8 commits to the same branch. By the way, you seem to have lost the tracking on the master branch. You need to restore it with `git branch -u origin/master`

Comment: I haven't done any changes in my local repository. Anyway I need to read more about git, because things can get messy. Thanks for your help.